# Showing a set is open through an inverse

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

The question:
Show that a set $U$ is open in the metric $M$ if and only if $U = f^{-1}(V)$ for some continuous function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and some open set $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$

I have no idea how to even begin on either side of this proof
My apologies if someone has answered this before but I could not find anything as such

Comment: Note: $f^{-1}(V)$ is not an inverse, but the preimage of $V$ under $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $C$ to be the complement of $U$, which is closed. Consider the function
$$
f(x) = \inf_{y \in C} d(x,y),
$$
also known as "distance from C". Exercise: prove that it is a continuous function.
Then $U = \{x : f(x) > 0\} = f^{-1}((0,\infty))$.